# ATmega168 Dimensions

Tags: arduino, atmega, dimensions

Anyone has the dimensions of the ATmega168? The on-board one, not the through-hole one. 
I need it, and after searching in the datasheet, I couldn't find it.

Comment: On-board what? Are you referring to the SMT version?

Comment: page 282 of the datasheet [here](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-9365-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega88-ATmega168_Datasheet.pdf).

Comment: *The on-board one* That's not what it's called, you mean: SMD or SMT version. Also I'm flabberghasted that you did not find this information in the datasheet. No datasheet would be complete without this information so it is there.

Comment: Yes, I meant SMD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know just what data sheet you are looking at but Atmel data sheets that I have looked at always have the dimensions included. See this one:

http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/268/Atmel-42176-ATmega48PB-88PB-168PB_Datasheet-1065517.pdf

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The package mechanical details are always in the data sheet or they point to where they are available.

In the case of the ATmega168 they are on page 425 of the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2545-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48-88-168_Datasheet.pdf)

[image]